# C++ Dynamic Array Access Violation, Reading & Writing Location

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to create an array inside of an array inside of an array which holds int values, I already know the lengths of all 3.

When changing or reading the value I get an access violation, imagine it's from creating the array within the loop, but I need to access and change these values outside of the loop, as the loop's purpose is to create more arrays within the initial array.

```
    //numFaces are defined by clipboard text being converted with std::stoi
    int ** meshFaces = new int*[numFaces];
    for(int i = 0; i < numFaces; i++) meshFaces[i] = new int[3];

    //expected meshFaces[num][2] = 0;


    std::cout << meshFaces[878] << "\n"; //test 3, prove range works

    //both cases cause access violation
    meshFaces[878][1] = 0; //test #2
    std::cout << meshFaces[878][1] << "\n"; //test


    // finished ref
    // 0 = Vertices
    // 1 = Normals
    // 2 = UVs
    // 
    // meshFaces[num][0][2] = 0

    //remove array from memory
    for(int i = 0; i < numFaces; i++) delete[] meshFaces[i];
    delete[] meshFaces;
```

Not sure how to fix this and get it to work the way I'd like.

Comment: what is `numFaces`? Is it > 878?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: Consider using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`. You might also consider allocating a single flat 1D array instead of a sparse 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider if
`std::cout << meshFaces[878] << "\n"; //test 3, prove range works`
is actually out of range, accessing past the end of allocated memory for `meshFaces` but it was not the last block of memory in the heap, so it returns *something* in memory, belonging to some other allocation.

Printing this as a pointer, it's no problem.

But it's not a pointer, it might be (say) part of a text string.  So trying to dereference the bad pointer gives the error.

`meshFaces[878]` returns (say) (0xff000102030405060708) which prints OK.  But then
`meshFaces[878][0]` gives an access violation.

Your test#3 does not prove the access in within range; it could be UB.  And it is easy to see that this may (quite easily) not crash at runtime, but the second subscript does.

"fix" it by checking the subscripting against `numFaces` before doing it.

However, it would use half the memory and be faster and simpler to use an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.  You can do this easily by using `std::array` which makes arrays act like normal (structure) types.

```
using meshdef = std::array<int,3>;
std::vector<meshdef> meshFaces (numFaces);
```

and then why not use `vector` and not worry about the manual memory management?  You only have *one* vector class overhead, not one per cell.

Comment: Thank you.
I'll make sure to practice with this information.

Coming from Lua I'm not quite familiar with C++

Comment: @Gel maybe you'll appreciate this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5249485/The-Most-Essential-Cplusplus-Advice   There are some essential reference pages noted.  Also, if you want to use `new`/`delete` _as a beginner_ I suspect whatever text or tutorial you're reading is vastly outdated.  Good luck, and keep at it.